# Conditionally apply className based on a status value in a React

Tags: css, reactjs

I have status column on listing page & i want to apply CSS class to  based on status value

```
if status == not_running    ||  running apply class =>  status-running

if status == completed  ||  success apply class =>  status-success

if status == cancelled  ||  failed      apply class =>  status-failed
```

[image]

So after applying classes status column will look like:

[image]

Comment: where is your code? Without code it is hard to imagine what exactly are you trying to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use ternary operators, as you can see the below code

```
<div className={status === "not_running" ? "status-running" : status == "completed" ? "status-success" : "status-failed"}>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [clsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clsx) for this. Otherwise, you can do ternary operator to add class conditionally